# C++ call a member function in another class while they two in the same class

Tags: c++

is there a solution for this problem? I just want to call a member function in another class while they two in the same class.

```
class ClassA {
public:
    void func() { printf("Hello World\n"); }
};

class ClassB {
public:
    void testfunc() {
        // TODO: call func() in classa;
    }
};

class ClassAB {
private:
    ClassA classa;
    ClassB classb;
public:
    ClassA& getClassa() { return classa; }
    ClassB& getClassb() { return classb; }
};

int main() {
    ClassAB classab;
    classab.getClassb().testfunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nope. C++ doesn't work this way.

Comment: You need to use :: instead of . Which is what more modern languages use.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of ClassA to invoke the func.

Perhaps you might pass the (only) instance you have in to testfunc():

```
// ...

class ClassB 
{
public:
   void testfunc(ClassA classa) 
   {
       classa.func();
   }
};

// ...

int main() 
{
   ClassAB classab;

   classab.getClassb().testfunc(classab.getClassa());

   return 0;
}
```

---

In your code, ClassA::func() is public, but not static.  You can only call a non-static public method attribute from an instance of ClassA.

Change func() to static and then yes, you can call it with ClassA::func(), from main, or anywhere the method is in scope.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly make **func()** public, which you have done.

Then it invoke **func()** from outside ClassA use:

```
    ClassA::func();
```

Comment: Try this yourself before suggesting this as an answer. It won't work. This only works with static class methods.